# How do you retrieve inputted text from a textbox array?

Tags: c#, arrays, input, textbox

I am creating a calculator where the user enters a number into a textbox specifing how many inputs (textboxes) the user wants to have (Code not shown). I have used a textbox array to create these textboxes. The problem comes when I want to get the text from these textboxes to perform the calculations, the code I have written so far for this is shown below:

```
int n;
TextBox[] textBoxes;
Label[] labels;
double[] values;

public void GetValue()
{
    n = Convert.ToInt16(txtInputFields.Text);
    values = new double[n];
    textBoxes = new TextBox[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {

    }
}
```

I am unsure what to put in the for loop for this; I have tried the following:

```
 values[n] = Convert.toDouble(textBoxes[n].Text);
```

but it gives me the error: **Index was outside the bounds of the array.**

I am new to C# and programming in general so any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

EDIT: Code to create textboxes is shown here:

```
public void InstantiateTextFields()
    {
        n = Convert.ToInt16(txtInputFields.Text);
        int posLeft = 100;
        textBoxes = new TextBox[n];
        labels = new Label[n];

        // Creates number of inputs and labels as specified in txtInputFields (n).
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            textBoxes[i] = new TextBox();
            textBoxes[i].Top = 100 + (i * 30);
            textBoxes[i].Left = posLeft;
            textBoxes[i].Name = "txtInput" + (i + 1);


            labels[i] = new Label();
            labels[i].Top = 100 + (i * 30);
            labels[i].Left = posLeft - 50;
            labels[i].Text = "Input " + (i + 1);
            labels[i].Name = "lblInput" + (i + 1);

        }

        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            this.Controls.Add(textBoxes[i]);
            this.Controls.Add(labels[i]);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Is this a WinForm or a Web Application? Show the code you use to create the textboxes.

Comment: Where do you fill the textbox array with the actual textboxes to be used for your calculation? The code above creates the array but it doesn't have any textbox to read texts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code in the `GetValue` method recreates the array of textboxes and doing so destroys the orginal content (the textboxes dynamically created `InstantiateTextFields`).
In this way your loop fails with `Object Reference not set`.

You just need to use the global variable without reinitiaizing it

```
public void GetValue()
{
    n = Convert.ToInt16(txtInputFields.Text);
    values = new double[n];

    // textBoxes = new TextBox[n];

    for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
    {
       values[i] = Convert.ToDouble(textBoxes[i].Text);

    }
}
```

There is something to be said about reading the input text and converting it to double without checks. If your user types something that cannot be converted to a double your code will crash on the Convert.ToDouble line. Use instead

```
double temp;
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
   if(double.TryParse(textBoxes[i].Text, out temp)
       values[i] = temp;
   else
   {
       // Not a double value....
       // A message to your user ?
       // fill the array with 0 ?
       // Your choice....
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

values[n] = Convert.toDouble(textBoxes[n].Text); gives you error because n is outside of the array. You allocate an array with the size of n which is zero indexed aka the last element is at position n-1.

```
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
{
    values[i] = Convert.toDouble(textBoxes[i].Text);
}
```

Comment: This gives me the error: **Object reference not set to an instance of an object.**. Thanks.

Comment: textBoxes = new TextBox[n]; allocates an array of textboxes however you also have to assign each reference to an instance of a textbox.